Oracle Apex - How to prevent escape HTML in e-mail templates?
I have simple e-mail template:
<br>
#DATA!RAW#
<br>

To send e-mail I use apex_mail.send, generate some tabular data:
{"DATA":"<table><tr><th>...."}

"!RAW" do not help, I still get whole DATA variable in double quotes in resulting e-mail.
How to prevent escape HTML in e-mail send from Apex?

Why "-1" already? Without any comments. Is it not enough info? I think question fairly simple.

After update of ORDS to 24.4 and DBMS to 19.25 "!RAW" works correctly and HTML doesn't get escaped.
